# issue with extracting tar.gz files using tar.gz npm module

Tags: node.js, tar, gzip

I have used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar.gz) package to recursively untar a given tar.gz file and move them to a destination . Program given below

```
var targz = require("tar.gz");
var fs = require("fs");

var s = "/home/user/test.tar.gz";
var d = "/home/user/destination";
var parse;
var readStream;

function extractTar(source, destination) {
    targz().extract(source, destination).then(function() {
    console.log("extracted " + source);
    readStream = fs.createReadStream(source);
    parse = targz().createParseStream();

    readStream.pipe(parse);
    parse.on('entry', function(entry) {
      var stringpath = destination+entry.path;
      if ((entry.path.length > 6) && entry.path.substr(entry.path.length - 6) === "tar.gz") {
        console.log(stringpath, destination);
        extractTar(stringpath, destination);
      }
      else {
        var filenameStartsAt = stringpath.lastIndexOf("/");
        filename = stringpath.substr(filenameStartsAt+1);
        if (filename.length) {
          console.log("===="+filename);
          fs.rename(stringpath, destination+filename, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }

          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

extractTar(s, d);
```

This works fine if there is already a folder named "destination" is in my directory. If destination folder is not present "destination" folder is created but that folder does not contains all extracted files in it. Some times there is not even one file in it. Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here on any better way to do this task.

Comment: The package `tar.gz` is now deprecated and considered vulnerable.